# Converting string of "bytes" to numpy array of uint8

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm using a API that returns RGB data as strings(*) (for instance I get `'ABC'` for `[65, 66, 67]`. Is there a way to have this directly converted to a numpy unint8 array without an explicit comprehension with `ord()`? Since this is picture data, I could be processing several million bytes, so any shortcut can help.

Otherwise, any method faster than the comprehension is gladly accepted.

(*) API requires Python 2.7, for the time being

Comment: can you give a little more of a [mcve]?  Like what's the shape of the data array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.frombuffer`:

```
np.frombuffer(b'ABC', dtype=np.uint8)
# array([65, 66, 67], dtype=uint8)
```

Since you are on Python2 this will probably work directly on strings, on Python3 a string would have to be encoded first to yield a bytes object.

Comment: Exactly what the doctor ordered... And yes, in Python2 it works directly on strings (I assume that in Python3, the API will give bytes and not strings). In addition, I figured out that I could use reshape() to get an array of RGB triplets.